# Migrations across databases with inconsistend database backend - Input?

Tags: python, sql, soap, artificial-intelligence, suds

I am migration some data from one database to another, it is production data that has accidentally ended up in a testing database.

It is typical a relational database centered around a single User table.

#### Things to consider

- Duplicate rows between *production* and *testing* may exist in almost any table.
- Any column in any User-related table in *testing* may miss content from *production*, or contain updated information due to User re-registration.
- All tables contain `created` and `updated` columns.

I have been connecting to the database via a SOAP layer because it is was the "easy" way. I do however have administration access to the machines running these databases.

Do you have any methods, any advice, any pointers for me to aid me in my goal to make this? Perhaps something along the lines of [Content Migration - Best Practices (PDF)](http://connectivity.opentext.com/common/whitepapers/Whitepaper_Content_Migration_Best_Practices_Report.pdf), anything, really.

Comment: I think we're missing some details... presumably it's not just a matter of dumping the DB from testing & importing into production?

Comment: I added some details about my environment. The problem is that I cannot determine historically which database has been written to.

Comment: This is not a typical migration.  This isn't the kind of thing that has "best practices", since the standard best practice is to check your configuration so that this can't happen.  (In some cases, i.e., Health Care, you may have created a HIPAA violation that could be a serious legal problem.)  You might want to change the title of your question.  You're really looking for a solution to a specific database misuse situation.  You should change the title to reflect that.

Comment: Good points @S.Lott, although the HIPAA is not relevant to my jurisdiction.

Comment: "Migration" isn't really the right word for this, still.  You're trying to merge data from two database sources.  You're doing something like "Master Data Management", where you're trying to find the good version, and ignore duplicates and out-of-date versions.  Migration usually means "test to production".  You don't seem to be doing that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Backup all the data first. It never hurts to say this!

**2.** Establish a reasonable sample size, i.e. how many records are you willing to look at in details, partly based on your time/money and the value of corrected accurate data.

**3.** Create a list, say in a spreadsheet of those records.

**4.** If you can, identify (externally) which ones are real, maybe using email address or other fields to compare with other data.

**5.** Look for patterns.  Is there any individual field:- id, date, user_id, etc that looks as if it will help you know which records are good?  Looks for value patterns, low/high ranges, duplicated 'sample' data (same value for a column in many records), dates without times, records with orphaned foreign ID's, there are a suprising number of things you can check!

**6.** Determine your final tolerance - are you looking for 100% ?  Or would 99.94% fixed be ok (well, acceptable then!) to the users?

**7.** Look at those duplicates you mentioned.  For those records, can you apply any rule such as 'older record' or 'newer record' or low ID number to at least eliminate them?

I hope this helps!